# Import an event from an ics file in the cli (zsh)?

Tags: macos, shell, calendar, zsh, icalendar

Does anyone know if it is possible to import an event into iCal from an ics file from the terminal/cli?

I have developed a web app which allows people to book a meeting with me and creates a valid ICS file which is then emailed to all parties invited to the meeting - this works fine and I can manually import the event by double clicking the ics file from the email attachments in MacOS.

However, I would like to import the event directly into iCal using a shell script so that I can automatically import all ics files in a given directory with a cron job or executed directly from the cli.

Anyone have any ideas how to go about this?  I am currently on MacOS Ventura 13.2 (a).

Comment: Yes, it is possible to import an event into iCal from an ICS file

Comment: Perhaps, in the spirit of answering the question, you could explain how?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself. 
Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), 
read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).